# Removing cyclic spikes from the data in dataframe using R

Tags: r

[image]

I have a data frame in below format, and My intension is to average out all the spike (**RED cyclical obs**) to a single common value so that I can remove those multiple spikes and have only one cyclic curve.

```
TimeStamp           Value
06-06-2017 05:15    58.12449265
06-06-2017 05:30    58.66942596
06-06-2017 05:45    60.08719635
06-06-2017 06:00    61.68566895
06-06-2017 06:15    61.58365631
06-06-2017 06:30    60.17367935
06-06-2017 06:45    58.30209351
06-06-2017 07:00    59.64432907
06-06-2017 07:15    61.5642128
06-06-2017 07:30    61.63970184
06-06-2017 07:45    61.54192734
06-06-2017 08:00    60.13797379
06-06-2017 08:15    58.82881546
```

So there is a particular trend in "Value" Its increasing from 58 and again decreasing all the way round to 58 in 1 hour and again increasing from 58 and decreasing down to 58.

Such instances are not present all over but only 2 hrs in every 24 hours.

I want this dataframe to be processed in below format, Where it should set Value against every 15 min to uniform so as to avoid peaks in data

```
TimeStamp           Value
06-06-2017 05:15    58.12449265
06-06-2017 05:30    58.66942596
06-06-2017 05:45    60.08719635
06-06-2017 06:00    61.XX
06-06-2017 06:15    61.XX
06-06-2017 06:30    61.XX
06-06-2017 06:45    61.XX
06-06-2017 07:00    61.XX
06-06-2017 07:15    61.XX
06-06-2017 07:30    61.XX
06-06-2017 07:45    61.XX
06-06-2017 08:00    60.13797379
06-06-2017 08:15    58.82881546
```

Comment: I don't really understand what you want to do, can you explain a little bit further? From 6:00 till 6:45 only one half of the values is above 61, nevertheless you want to have them set to 61. What is the explicity rule here?

Comment: There is no explicit rule but I just want to set the values to uniform when they are fluctuating within same range in 2 to 3 hour interval. So in above scenario in 3 hour interval values are fluctuating from 58 -60 -61-60-59-58 -59-60-61-60-58 , What i want is to smooth that trend and average out  middle range to constant value

Comment: Hmm... Maybe something like a smoothing average is more whath you're looking for?

Comment: yeah just want to smooth out cyclic fluctuations, but the challenge is this fluctuations are not present all over the data but only at few instance